# Plotting pivot table results from two groups into subplots in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a pivot table with `pd.pivot_table` with two columns `loc` and `sub` resulting in the following table:

```
#example data
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'times': ['2019', '2020', '2019', '2020', '2019', '2020', '2019', '2020'],
                   'values': [0, 5, 10, 15, 3, 5, 10, 15],
                   'sub': ['N', 'N', 'P', 'P', 'N', 'N', 'P', 'P'],
                   'loc': ['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2']})
```

[image]

Now I want to make subplots for all uniques  of `loc` separately but with all the  `sub` uniques in the same subplot.
Using this code results in 2 columns for the `sub` uniques with the number of rows as `loc` uniques:

```
subs = ['N', 'P']
locs = ['1', '2']

pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),
               index='times', columns=['loc', 'sub'], values='values'
               ).plot(subplots=True, kind='area', grid=True, legend=True, stacked=False, sharex=True,
                      layout=(len(locs), len(subs)))
```

Example results

[image]

This is the current plot result with all instances separated into subplots:
[image]

The ultimate goal is to merge the different `sub` columns.

Comment: Pandas/matplolib/seaborn are not great with plotting multiindex dataframes. Seaborn is usually the first choice because you have to reshape the dataframe less frequently than when using pandas/matplotlib. But - there is always a but - it does not have native support for area plots. So - you might be better off to plot from a dataframe before pivoting. What is the structure of this dataframe? That of `df`?